# RevMob sdk 5.9.0 gives error on header file while import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>

Tags: iphone, ios, revmob, revmobads

I have already integrated RevMobs in my project. Now I just update it and download new sdk 5.9.0 and follow same step as before and also refer this link

[RevMob ios sdk](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios.html)

But now i can't integrate it and while importing header file

```
#import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>
```

it gives an error.

Please help me to solve it.

Here is my snap:

[image]

Comment: whats the error you are getting? post the error

Comment: @SharanyaKM :can now you help me?

Comment: My "Phantom Folder issue" answer is what solved it for me in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250638/revmobads-revmobads-h-file-not-found/19813037#19813037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case When I followed steps as per SHARANYA's answer , i saw in my Build Phases there are no such files.
Then, I tried to import it in Build Phase but could not import it.

When i added the Header Search Path i got the actual problem solved.

Hope this will Help Some One.

Comment: can you paste your path ?

Answer (score 2):

One of these should work

1)Open the target of your project.
2)Open the the "Build Phases"
3)Expand the "Compile Sources"
4)Delete the filename that is causing the error
5)Add the file back.

**OR**

In `Header Search Paths` you will need to add the path for your files. To change this you will need to go to project's build settings and search for `Header Search Paths` and then add the path for your file

Comment: @its help me.Actually my Framework search parth was mess up.And thats why its not get that file.
Thanks you

Comment: Yeah. You must have drag and drop the framework to your XCode and you forgot to select the "Copy items into destination ..." check box.

Answer (score 0):

just go to header search path and add "$SCROOT" and make it recursive

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I managed to solve this. I read a lot of questions here, and searched online.

[This article help me out a lot.](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html)

So, what happened to me, is that the library files, that were giving to me were missing some files and shortcodes.

So, I just:

1. Downloaded the new version of the library. [Link here.](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html#download)
2. Copy to my project folder.
3. Add it to the Header Search Path. (Build Settings, Search Path, Header Search Paths. Add something like $`(PROJECT_DIR)/RevMobAds.framework`)
4. And a Clean, Build.
5. And that's it.