# 'RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h' file not found

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am unable to find the problem of this Error. Can anyone guide me. How to fix given below error. 
I had added the revmob sdk in my project and i had also checked the box "Copy to destination if needed." And i also checked it is there in the xcode project. but still given below error is not going. This not my first time i am integrated revmob. but do not know why suddenly this error starts appearing even this code is working fine before.

Error
'RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h' file not found

Comment: delete all files and added once again...

Comment: yes i try this too. i deleted sdk, clean build folder. and then close xcode. reopen it and add sdk. but same error.

Comment: are you following this tutorial http://sdk.revmob.com/ios.html????

Comment: Yes, i am following it

Comment: Check this thread for an alternative answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853732/revmob-sdk-5-9-0-gives-error-on-header-file-while-import-revmobads-revmobads-h

Comment: this is the [problem in my xCode][1] as jsherk commented


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16854620/644149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I call this the "Phantom Folder issue"...

I had an issue where I deleted the RevMobAds.framework from within Xcode but when I tried to re-add the newer SDK by dragging and dropping into Xcode into a different folder (copy was checked and targets were checked), it would appear then give me the same error: 'RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h' file not found

It turns out that when I checked the real project folder in Finder (not from within Xcode) that an empty RevMobAds.framework folder was left behind.

So what I did was:

(1) From Xcode, deleted the RevMobAds.framework that I had added.

(2) Went to the real project folder in Finder and deleted any phantom/leftover folders named RevMobAds.framework that were still there.

(3) Dragged the RevMobAds.framwork SDK back into Xcode (making to sure to check COPY and targets).

And this solved the problem for me.

Comment: if it still do not solve the problem then go to header search path in project seting and delete the old refrences and add correct refrence to the revmobads.framework folder. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16854620/644149

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on your App in groups and files section, Select Add files to "your app"....

Once you do that, select folder you want to add and select "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" as shown in screenshot below.

Note: Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed) is to be selected only if the files are physically in some other folder and not the application bundle or application folder.

Comment: Sounds right, this error occurs if the files weren't copied into the application's folder when you first added the Revmob Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I managed to solve this. I read a lot of questions here, and searched online.

[This article help me out a lot.](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html)

So, what happened to me, is that the library files, that were giving to me were missing some files and shortcodes.

So, I just:

1. Downloaded the new version of the library. [Link here.](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html#download)
2. Copy to my project folder.
3. Add it to the Header Search Path. (Build Settings, Search Path, Header Search Paths. Add something like $`(PROJECT_DIR)/RevMobAds.framework`)
4. And a Clean, Build.
5. And that's it.