# RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h file not found

Tags: xcode

I have search this issue already and the 2 solutions that I've found was to delete the SDK and reinstall - change the search path to "$(SRCROOT). Neither of these solutions worked - any other suggestions? I did reach out to RevMob support Im just waiting to hear back but sometimes that can take a day. Just hoping I could find a quicker answer.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you installing the SDK by dragging and dropping the framework?

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RevMob sdk 5.9.0 gives error on header file while import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853732/revmob-sdk-5-9-0-gives-error-on-header-file-while-import-revmobads-revmobads-h)